# Python - Converting a column with weekly data to a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following date column that I would like to transform to a pandas datetime object. Is it possible to do this with weekly data? For example, 1-2018 stands for week 1 in 2018 and so on. I tried the following conversion but I get an error message: Cannot use '%W' or '%U' without day and year

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date"])
df1['date'] = ["1-2018", "1-2018", "2-2018", "2-2018", "3-2018", "4-2018", "4-2018", "4-2018"]

df1["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["date"], format = "%W-%Y")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a day to the `datetime` format

```
df1["date"] = pd.to_datetime('0' + df1["date"], format='%w%W-%Y')
print(df1)
```

Output

```
        date
0 2018-01-07
1 2018-01-07
2 2018-01-14
3 2018-01-14
4 2018-01-21
5 2018-01-28
6 2018-01-28
7 2018-01-28
```

Answer (score -1):

As the error message says, you need to specify the day of the week by adding %w :

```
df1["date"] = pd.to_datetime( '0'+df1.date, format='%w%W-%Y')
```

Comment: You just copied my answer.

Comment: I didn't see it, had this tab open for a bit